# React not rendering <th> under loop

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

name and Product under th tag gets rendered but the loop for  doesn't get rendered..but i can see the values in console.nad doesn't throw any error...please hemp

```
<tr>
   <th>name</th>
   <th>productID</th>
     {this.state.product[0].customCoulmns.forEach(function (columnhead) {
     console.log("columnhead lolzz ",columnhead.columnName);
     return <th key={columnhead.columnName}>{columnhead.columnName}</th>
        }.bind(this))
  }
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything to the caller. You should be using a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```
this.state.product[0].customCoulmns.map(function (columnHead) {
    return <th key={columnHead.columnName}>{columnHead.columnName}</th>
})
```

Note that there's no need to bind `this` here. It is only necessary to do this when you need a reference to `this` and the original value will no longer be in scope when the function is called. In this case, neither of those conditions are true.

Also, as a general piece of advice, take care with your spelling and casing consistency in your code :)